# Dynamic CSS Styles with Vendor Prefixes in Angular 2

Tags: css, angular

Let's say I want to write a component in Angular 2 that has two input arguments: `colorOne` and `colorTwo`. What the component should do is to fill a `<div>` with the gradient of those two colors.

If I just wanted to give the `div` a background color of `colorOne` it wouldn't be a problem, I could just use `<div [style.background]="colorOne" class="my-box"></div>`. However, if I want to give it a background **gradient**, I wouldn't know how to do it nicely, because `background-gradient` needs to be vendor prefixed. The only solution I could think of was checking in javascript which browser is used. Something like:

```
  public get headerColor () {

    //... determine the browser

    let backgroundStyle = `linear-gradient(left top, ${this.colorOne}, ${this.colorTwo})`;
    if (isWebkit) {
      backgroundStyle = "-webkit-" + backgroundStyle;
    } else if (isO) {
      backgroundStyle = "-o-" + backgroundStyle;
    } else if (isMoz) {
      backgroundStyle = "-moz-" + backgroundStyle;
    }

    return backgroundStyle;

  };
```

and then use `<div [style.background]="headerColor" class="my-box"></div>`. Is there a better solution than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return a single string that contains all of the various prefixed values; only the relevant one will be used:

```html
<div [style]="stylish" class="my-box"></div>
```

```ts
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, ...) { ... }

get stylish() {
    let basicStyle = `linear-gradient(left top, ${this.colorOne}, ${this.colorTwo})`;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`
      background: -o-${basicStyle};
      background: -moz-${basicStyle};
      background: -webkit-${basicStyle};
    `);
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works! I tried this, but without the sanitizer, so it didn't work before when I tried.