# Angular ngstyle stripping -webkit-

Tags: angular, ng-style

The code below is working in Chrome but it seems to be stripping `-webkit-` or `-moz-` or `-o-` which is disabling me to show it in all browsers properly.

```
[ngStyle]="{'-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + ((marks.result * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)'}"
```

gets compiled into `style="transform: rotate(-59.4deg);"`

I need it to retain the original code in such a way that it outputs as `style="-webkit-transform: rotate(-59.4deg);"`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is it lab you are doing ?:D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert number to degrees in ngStyle using Angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061404/convert-number-to-degrees-in-ngstyle-using-angular-8)

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat - How can [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061404/convert-number-to-degrees-in-ngstyle-using-angular-8) answer his question?

Comment: We are actually working together on a project. Everything is working finally but we just realised that `ngStyle` is stripping the `-webkit-transform` to `transform` which disables our speedometer to work in the compiled PDF. So we need a solution to figure out a way to disable stripping the `-webkit-`. Thank you.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I thought firstly that its kind of lab since similar question was asked already today.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'll need to use DomSanitizer `bypassSecurityTrustStyle`. See this answer: [Dynamic CSS Styles with Vendor Prefixes in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611621/dynamic-css-styles-with-vendor-prefixes-in-angular-2)

Angular by default normalizes class names and drops the vendor prefixes. Below is the code snippet from that answer:

```ts
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, ...) { ... }

get stylish() {
    let basicStyle = `linear-gradient(left top, ${this.colorOne}, ${this.colorTwo})`;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`
      background: -o-${basicStyle};
      background: -moz-${basicStyle};
      background: -webkit-${basicStyle};
    `);
}
```

It also shows using it as:

```html
<div [style]="stylish"></div>
```

I'm not sure if you can use `ngStyle`, or if you will need to use `ngStyle`.

You may need to make some changes, as the answer is a couple years old, but I believe that's ultimately what you'll need to do

Comment: This isn't working. I'm getting this instead `style="ng-reflect-ng-style="SafeValue must use [property]="`

Comment: @NikitaGupta what does your code look like? You need to use the property binding syntax `[style]="..."`. Note the square brackets around `style`.

Comment: This is the complete code: `<div class="needle" style="background-image: url('http://example.com/assets/images/needle.png')" [ngStyle]="{'transform': 'rotate(' + ((marks.result * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)','-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + ((marks.result * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)','-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + ((marks.result * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)','-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + ((marks.result * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)','-o-transform': 'rotate(' + ((marks.result * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)'}"></div>`

Comment: You'll need to add a function or getter in your component.ts class that uses the `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle` method. Like I supplied in my answer.

Comment: I actually did. There's no more error from my end and it compiled too but I got the error as shown in my first comment here.

Comment: Are you using `[ngStyle]` or `[style]`? If ngStyle, try just style.

Comment: `[style]="stylish"` didn't show anything. [ngStyle] gave the response as shown in the first comment.